# Is it possible to put "default TEXT" in "CSS style file"?

Tags: html, css

I need this "default text" in my CSS file, for example to an `<input>` tag and to a `<textarea>`,

so I search for something like:

```
 <style>
   testcss{
    default:"DefaultText";
     or 
    value:"DefaultText";
   }
 </style>
```

So, here is my question, 
I have several `<input>` in my form, and I need to set them all "same default value"! for example same "placeholter" ou same "value" and, I need this by CSS `<style>`!

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with this and what are the specific tags you need to keep default values for?

Comment: Yes you can do this see my answer!

Comment: By "default text", are you referring to a placeholder? Or are you referring to the initial value of the input element?

Comment: So a have several < input > in my form, and I need to set them all "same default value"! for example same "placeholter" ou same "value" and, I need this by CSS <style> !

Comment: @RobervalSena山本 You can do this see my Answer? I added a fiddle to that you can just see it how it works live!

Comment: Yes! I see and already tested!!   It give me some ideas!  tks a lot!

Comment: A placeholder is not a value, and a value is not a placeholder. Which one do you want?

Comment: hi torazaburo, thanks for your patient, once I do not know how to do this,  I beliave this is a part of the question, I re-write the question...  i did not know it was so hard to put one default value for all "placeholder" in the < input > tags...   by css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = "Default Text";
}
```

Comment: This one give me a lot of ideas! and sove my problem! tks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, with a `<label>` placed behind the input using z-index and a transparent background-color on the `<input>`. Use `:focus` to change to a white background. Use `:valid` `:invalid` that the placeholder don't shine through if text is entered. With `.input:before` your "styling" the content of the label. `:first-line has sometimes some Firefox issues`. With my Firefox for mac it worked with this code.

## HTML

```
<label class="input"><input type="text" required="required"/></label>
```

## CSS

```
.input {
    color: gray;
    display: block;
    font-size: small;
    padding-top: 3px;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: 5px;
}

input {
    background-color: transparent;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

input:focus, input:first-line {
    background-color: white;
}

.input:before {
    content: "Some CSS Text";
}

input:valid { background-color:white; }
input:invalid{ background-color:transparent; }
```

## Screenshot (chrome browser)

1. without Text
2. without text and focus
3. with text and focus
4. with text in it.

[image: without text]
[image: without text and focus]
[image: with focus]
[image: with text]

See https://jsfiddle.net/uueojg2g/1/ for testing.

## Summary

Would I recommend using css for your task? Perhaps not, cause you should use css for presentation only. So I would always to try to get a html variant with placeholder

## How it works with "pure" html

Preferred method, and works in all current browsers:

```
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="Full Name"/>
```

For IE9 and before, we just need some javascript:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="Full Name" onfocus="value=''" onblur="value='Full Name'"/>
```

Comment: What does "placed behind the index" mean?

Comment: @torazaburo misspelling. Should be placed behind the input field. Thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use html for content and css for presentation.

So you could actually do that inside of inside of html input tag by using value attribute:

```
<input value="default text">
```

As for the text area, you put the default value in between the tags:

```
<textarea> default text </textarea>
```

You can use javascript or jquery to make it more convenient, like making the default text disappear when user clicks on textarea, or input element, but that is out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the text styling used by default in the HTML as follow:

```html
<style>font-family: sans-serif;</style>
```